# How to test private fun returning Mono?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, project-reactor

everyone!
I know how to unit test private fun with reflection:

```
@Test
    fun testFun() {
        val method = myService.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("getSomeThing", SomethingDto::class.java)
        method.isAccessible = true
        val somethingDto = SomethingDto(id = UUID.randomUUID())
        val parameters = arrayOfNulls<Any>(1)
        parameters[0] = somethingDto
        method.invoke(myService,*parameters)
    }
```

And, for testing functions, returning Mono, I use .block():

```
@Test
    fun testCreate() {
        val somethingDto = SomethingDto(id = UUID.randomUUID())
        myService.create(somethingDto).block()

    }
```

But if I need to test private fun, like in 1st example, but fun returns Mono, how can I do it?

This doesn't work

```
method.invoke(myService,*parameters).block()
and 
method.invoke(myService,*parameters).toMono().block()
```

grateful for your help

Comment: I assume the private function you are trying to test is yours. If so, and it forms a piece of logic for a larger public function then consider making it internal rather than private. Your test in the same package can then access it, and you can also mock it using a spy to test higher level functions.

Comment: I agree with @Laurence : you should rather use `internal` functions, and avoid using reflections. Also, to test behaviour of reactive-streams, you can use Reactor test framework and its `StepVerifier` class. See [Reactor reference documentation: Testing section](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#testing).